# js form: mixed textarea and input types causes wrong focus on click

Tags: javascript

I have a working an in-house form that generates some html code when users enter field data.

problem is i have a single 'textarea' object mixed in with 20 or so other 'input type' objects, and focus is always sent to the text area when any form object below it is clicked.

I have tried with and without tabindex values. But, really the tab order is not the issue (tab order works fine). The problem is when a user manually clicks any field on the form, the cursor is taken to the 'textarea' field.

so, to replicate the issue, load the form below. try to click on any form element below the text area. when an element is clicked focus is put on the textarea field.

here's the full form:

http://devtest.host.org/testing/test-form.html

thanks.

Comment: TrendMicro security scan blocked access to your link. I'm guessing you have invalid markup somewhere (or need to change the `for` attribute values on any `label` tags you might have.)

Comment: I'm not sure why all the `<input type="text" />` elements are wrapped in a `<label>`, but at the same time, the `<label>` is not pointing at the textarea, so that's weird.

Comment: FWIW, I repurposed the form here. Not sure why the input types are wrapped in <label> either. but, that's what worked in this case:http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=176870

Comment: Hmm well the way you should use `<label>` elements is the `for` attribute, which specifies the `id` of the element to focus on when clicked. So you'd want something like `<label for="text1">First:</label><input type="text" id="text1" />`

Comment: And it's probably not best that most of the page is wrapped in a `<label>` element entirely as well.

Comment: Consider using W3 Validation tools such as this one: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: just did a find/replace and removed the label tags altogether. they are not needed. i guess that's what i get from cheating off the kid next to me ;-) thanks for the help.